# I get MAPI_E_UNKNOWN_ENTRYID when do GetMessageFromID() in thread through Redemption

Tags: c#, multithreading, outlook, mapi, outlook-redemption

I used Redemption (http://dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm) for develop my Outlook AddIn. When I try GetMessageFromId in STA-thread(!) at first time all good, but in next times i get MAPI_E_UNKNOWN_ENTRYID.

```
    RDOSession rdoSession = null;.
    rdoSession = new RDOSession();
    if (rdoSession != null)
    {
         if (!rdoSession.LoggedOn) 
            rdoSession.Logon(Consts.ProfileName);
         if (rdoSession.LoggedOn)
         {
           for (int c = 1; c <= rdoStoresCnt; c++)
           { 
            /* other code */
            RDOMail mail = null;
            try
            {
               mail = rdoSession.GetMessageFromID(entryID);
               /*  other code  */
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
             if (mail != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mail); mail = null;
            }
            finally
            {
             if (mail != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mail); mail = null;
            }
           }
        } 
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MAPI_E_UNKNOWN_ENTRYID` means the current MAPI session (created by calling `RDOSession.Logon`) does not know which MAPI provider is supposed to handle the specified entry id because (most likely) the provider has not been loaded yet in that session and did nto have a chance to register its set of entry ids with the MAPI system in the session.

You can try to specify the store entry id when calling `GetMessageFromId` (Redemption will open the specified store first and call `IMsStore::OpenEntry` instead of `IMAPISession::OpenEntry`), but the real solution is avoid creating a brand new MAPI session at all - since your code is inside Outlook, there is already the MAPI session used by Outlook: simply set the `RDOSession.MAPIOBJECT` property to `Namespace.MAPIOBJECT` from Outlook. Do **not** call `RDOSession.Logoff` in that case.

Comment: Thanks for response. But I can't set the `RDOSession.MAPIOBJECT` to `Namespace.MAPIOBJECT` because it works into thread, or I'm wrong?

Comment: Thanks. Using `RDOStore` at call `GetMessageFromId` was helped.

Comment: Do set the MAPIOBJECT property, do NOT create a new session inside your addin. The threading will be perfectly fine - store the value of Namespace.MAPIOBJECT on the main thread. On the secondary thread, create new instance of RDOSession, set the MAPIOBJECT property to the value saved on the main thread. This way the Namespace OOM object is never passed between threads, only IMAPISession from the MAPIOBJECT property (which is perfectly fine).